# Co-occurence matrix on multilabel data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a dataset of users, each user can belong to multiple classes :

```
user1, A
user1, B
user1, C
user2, A
user2, C
user3, B
user3, C
```

For example in this case, user1 belongs to class A, B and C. I would like to know how many unique users are in each pair of classes (each entry in the table corresponds to the number of shared unique users):

```
  | A | B | C
A | 2 | 1 | 1
B | 1 | 2 | 2
C | 1 | 2 | 2
```

I wonder how is it possible to do it with dataframes and RDD in PySpark? I think maybe I need to reshape the data/pivot but the solutions I come up with seem a bit complicated for the task...

Thank you!

Comment: Please rephrase, since it is unclear what you are asking; in the initial dataset you show there are not any pairs of classes... Are you missing something?

Comment: @desertnaut my fault. The objective is to know the number of shared unique users in each pair of classes. For example, user1 belong to A, B and C, then there is at least one user shared between (A and B), (B and C) and (A and C). Is it clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-join by class and `crosstab`

```
(df.withColumnRenamed("class", "class_a")
    .join(df.withColumnRenamed("class", "class_b"), ["user"])
    .crosstab("class_a", "class_b")
    .orderBy("class_a_class_b")
    .show())

# +---------------+---+---+---+ 
# |class_a_class_b|  A|  B|  C|
# +---------------+---+---+---+ 
# |              A|  2|  1|  2|
# |              B|  1|  2|  2|
# |              C|  2|  2|  3|
# +---------------+---+---+---+
```

Apply distinct before if you want only unique `(user, class)` pairs.